# Creating a function name on the fly (dynamically) - PHP

Tags: php, function, callback, hook

Below is the code that I'm working with.

```
function my_tab( $tabs ) {

    // the following array will be created dynamically
    $colors = array("red", "white", "blue");

    foreach ($colors as $value) {
        $tabs[$value] = array(
            'name' => $value
        );  

        // start creating functions
        function content_for_[$value]() {
            echo "this is the " .$value. " tab";
        }
        // stop creating functions

        add_action('content_for_'.$value, 'content_for_'.$value);
    }
    return $tabs;

}
```

As you can see, I have an array that's created dynamically. For each `color` I need to create a `function`. These functions are tied into `hooks` and the function names have to `exist`. So far, everything I've tried for the past 6 hours results in an error similar to:

> "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'content_for_green' not found or invalid function name"

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to create a [hook in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)? If you are hooking to a custom event, then your trigger should pass the `$value` as a parameter. I am not a Wordpress expert, but if you share the code that triggers the action, I can probably help you with some example.

Comment: Is this what you're asking for?

do_action("content_for_{$nav}", $args);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP >= 5.3, you can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php), e.g.

```
add_action( 'content_for_' . $value, function() use ( $value ) {
      echo "this is the " . $value . " tab";
   }
);
```

With `use` keyword are allowing the anonymous function to capture the variables from current scope (e.g. `$value` in your case).

Comment: I placed my code into its own file. Replaced my 'create functions' area with your code.  At the end I placed content_for_red();   That results in the following error...

Fatal error: Call to undefined function content_for_red() in C:\xampp\htdocs\createfunction\index.php on line 22

Comment: Thank you vitozev.  Your answer was the solution. I must've had a typo in it the first time I tried.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly don't want to do that, this is horrible practice. Using closures, [as vitozev advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635798/1446005), is sensibly less ugly, but is still hard to maintain voodoo magic.

Instead, just add a parameter to your callback, e.g. by expanding your existing parameter array:

```
function content_for_color_callback($args) {
    echo 'this is the ' . $args['color'] . ' tab';
}
```

Simply register the hook:

```
add_action('content_for_color', 'content_for_color_callback');
```

... and pass `color` as a standard parameter, :

```
// do not do this
do_action("content_for_{$nav}", $args);

// do this instead
$args['color'] = $nav;
do_action('content_for_color', $args);
```

One of the many advantages with this approach is that you have a much less room for obscure errors. For example, imagine someone feels like calling a non-existing `content_for_bazinga()` function. With your approach, you would get an obscure

> Call to undefined function content_for_bazinga()

Compare with:

```
function content_for_color_callback($args) {
    $color = $args['color'];
    if( !colorIsValid($color)) {
        throw new Exception("There is no such tab: $color");
    }
    echo "This is the $color tab";
}
```