# How to create a dynamic function inside foreach loops in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, foreach

I am trying to loop through an `array` using `foreach` loops and for each elements I want to create a separate function.

```
$items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

foreach( $items as $item ){
    function $item."_output"(){
        echo $item.' success';
    }
}
```

My expectation is to create function for each array element like:
`function one_output(){}`, `function two_output(){}`, `function three_output(){}`

Comment: Why you need this?

Comment: I am trying to make a WordPress plugin where I have to deal with this issue.

Comment: What’s the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a function name on the fly (dynamically) - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635594/creating-a-function-name-on-the-fly-dynamically-php)

Comment: You can't create *named* functions from variables without using eval, because function names are identifiers which must exist when the PHP interpreter parses the code, and creating things using variable values happens at runtime. You can create anonymous functions using variable variables, but that may not work for what you're trying to do. Will these functions be used as callbacks in your WP plugin? I think there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, these are the callback function and trying to find a better way.

Comment: Using the anonymous callback function will solve the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create functions directly. But instead you can create [closures (anonymous functions)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and put them into an array:

```
<?php
  $items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  $myfuncs = array();

  foreach( $items as $item ) {
      // create a function which uses current value of $item
      $myfuncs[$item] = function() use ($item) { 
         echo  $item.' success';
      };
  }

  $myfuncs['one'](); // one success

  $myfuncs['two'](); // two success
```